# ParseExact without time in format gives 12:00 AM

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

When I parse a date without time part I get a datetime with 12:00 AM.
I expect it to be 00:00 AM

```
 DateTime.ParseExact( "1/10/2014", "d/MM/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None );
```

Despite my OS's culture being nl-BE, my (specflow) thread's culture seems to be en-US.
Why do I get a date with a time part of 12:00 AM?

**For the googlers:**

- For debugging a datetime's hours check the timeofday property. It's always in ISO
- 00:00 == 12:00 AM, but 01:00 == 01:00 AM
- AM PM is god damn confusing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock

Comment: Are you sure? It is `00:00` on me. Your culture doesn't have any AM/PM designator by the way.

Comment: There is no such thing as "00:00 AM" -- AM and PM take positive numbers for the hours. "12:00 AM" is midnight ("00:00" in the 24-hour clock). Are you really having a problem with how dates and times are formatted, perhaps?

Comment: Note that this won't work if your current culture doesn't use `/` as date-separator(as for `"nl-NL"` for example) because it's [a special format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator). You have to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null`(current culture) or use `"d'/'MM'/'yyyy"` instead.

Comment: @SonerGönül .. I'm looking at the debugger window right now.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Should I? Even if I'm using parseexact and passing in a format? Will check this out

Comment: @BorisCallens Yes of course. You need `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` otherwise `date-separator` for current culture will be used.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Ah I see. That adds another layer of complexity. Man I hate dateTimes!

Comment: @BorisCallens: yes, because `/` means "replace me with the actual date-separator of the curent culture". Try it with `new CultureInfo("nl-NL")` instead of `null` (or `new CultureInfo("nl-BE")`). You'll get a `FormatException` because in the netherlands they use `-` as separator.

Comment: @BorisCallens Your culture has `/` as a date separator. Don't worry :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Pardon my thick skull, but if 00:00 = 12:00AM, then  is 01:00 13:00 AM? That can't be right? How about the whole world just goes ISO?

Comment: @BorisCallens: Of course not, don't be silly -- 01:00 is 1 AM, of course. :-) And yes, whenever you have the option, use ISO -- there is not really any excuse for not doing so except when presenting dates and times to the end user and when getting manual input.

Comment: This question seems to have been edited so there isn't actually a question in it any more...

Comment: @Chris You are right. In my effort to give it a bit of structure I hid the actual question. Do you agree that my latest edit made it better?

Comment: @BorisCallens: Indeed. We have a question again! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

12:00 AM is midnight, and so the very first second of the given date, and therefore a correct result. It is not necessary to subtract 12 hours, that would in fact produce noon the day before the given date. The first minute after midnight is 00:01 AM.

To modify the culture of the current thread, simply write:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("nl-BE");
```

and your code will run as Dutch (Belgium).

Comment: Hey Roy, thanks for your answer. I know about thread cultures (as I described in the OP), but changing it doesn't answer the question.